# How to use Onionkit with Volley

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, android-volley, verification, onionkit

The app I am working on uses Onionkit to do TSL/SSL certificate verification. I added Volley support in the app, but realized that Volley only supports the Apache HttpClient, while Onionkit uses the boye.androidlib HttpClient. So these 2 do not work together.
Right now I am using the fork of Volley at here https://github.com/kulik/volley.git, it works with the boye library so my app is working.

However I would rather just use Volley. Is there a way to make it work? I looked at HurlStack class, it has the SSLSocketFactory field. I suppose this one will work for the Cert verification. But I have not figured out a way to get it work. Sorry for the kind of vague question but I am not a security expert. When using the Onikit, I passed in the cert pins to the TrustManager. However I have not found a way to link the SSLFactory with the TrustManager. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Ray

Comment: I would recommend to switch to retrofit library by square.  It handles the TTL/SSL connection for you without defining the trust manager etc.

Comment: I can use the ssl connection without setting up the trust manager, however that will not be able to prevent the man in the middle attack.

Answer (score 2):

You can use HurlStack to use different HttpClient implementations. For example,  see [how to use OkHttp with Volley:](https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/5616899)

```
public class OkHttpStack extends HurlStack {
  private final OkHttpClient client;

  public OkHttpStack() {
    this(new OkHttpClient());
  }

  public OkHttpStack(OkHttpClient client) {
    if (client == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("Client must not be null.");
    }
    this.client = client;
  }

  @Override protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
    return client.open(url);
  }   
}
```

and use it with

```
Volley.newRequestQueue(context, new OkHttpStack())
```

It should be easy to derive how to use your http client from that. If you want to use your own SSL logic you can overwrite this method from HurlStack

```
private static SSLSocketFactory createPinnedSSLCertFactory(Context ctx) {
    //create your implementation 
}
```

I dont really know what exactly you want to do here but here is an example that loads an empty keystore and pins it to only 1 cert (any others would not be accepted -> ssl pinning)

```
private static SSLSocketFactory createPinnedSSLCertFactory(Context ctx) {
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    Certificate myCert = //read certificate in;
    String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
    keyStore.load(null, null); //inputstream null creates new keystore
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("mycert", myCert );

    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    tmf.init(keyStore);

    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

    return context.getSocketFactory();
}
```

Note: I had problems with creating my own SSLFactory with Gingerbread (2.3) and lower meaning it didn't work.

Comment: This looks promising, thanks. I did not notice the createConnection before. Will check it out. As for your question about what I want to do. I was thinking just use the HUrlConnection without using the HttpClient. The most important thing for me is to do the cert pinning. Currently I have several pins for different certificates. I do not have the certificates themselves. How that can be done using the SSLSocketFactory?  Thanks

Comment: You cannot pin certs you do not have (thats the whole point :), but you can easily download them with e.g. your browser. Also I have alreay put the example up how to pin a cert you can extend it from there.

Comment: The OKHttpStack does not seem working. My http client is ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient, it is not derived from the URL class, so it is not accepted by the createConnection method.

Comment: Well I think then you are out of luck and stuck with the fork as there seems no easy way to plugin your http client.